# Create object with template literal types and generic

Tags: typescript

I try to create an Object with the new Typescript 4.1 literal types feature.
But if generic come into place, everything breaks.
What I'm missing?

```js
export type MyType<T extends string> = {
  propFromMyType: T;
};

export type TypeWithGenericLiteral<T extends string> = {
  [P in `${T}_with_literal`]: number;
};

// works fine
export const create1 = (t: MyType<"example">): TypeWithGenericLiteral<"example"> => {
    const prop = `${t.propFromMyType}_with_literal` as const;

    return {
        [prop]: 777
    };
}

// does not work
export const create2 = <T extends "example"> (t: MyType<T>): TypeWithGenericLiteral<T> => {
    const prop = `${t.propFromMyType}_with_literal` as const;

    return {
        [prop]: 777
    };
} 


// does not work
export const create3 = <T extends string> (t: MyType<T>): TypeWithGenericLiteral2<T> => {
    const prop = `${t.propFromMyType}_with_literal` as const;

    return {
        [prop]: 777
    };
}
```

[link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBZZAVVIA82C4cIAdgCYDOCVcMAlmQOYB8CAvAgN7AIIQYUCADEhAWyy40ALgTYA3MAC+S0JFiIUaeXgDqDOAAsA4uRCMAxgBlDFgIYAbQsTClKNOoxbsuvfgDaAAoITAgABgAk3NjKAPoA7oZGcY52ME7hALpyZACu4gBGFkqqwOXg0PAIllBkdDUwIPakAIycCAAUcHJSePgAROD24hCOIAOsAJRy0iAGxmZkFgw26U6Dw6Pjk5zs-vw1dQ2Cwh1R3HAAdKeiEn1o8UnGqeuO4Qj2NLX1cGqHCCacDyMDIPD4AMOAVuOQQAHYERD+GVlOUAPRohAUKAgGhkKCIBKwADW6iqiB+DUsTRaIAATB0XCRyNQEEMwCMxhN2N1ejh+thprN9Mklis1qQMs5BXtwQDKYhbudotdbmIoJJ+Y9EslXpLMp9vsc-uUAUCQWCDpCENChBBYQi4UiECiEOVgBisTi8QSEESYKTKpojr9Gs1SABmRlEZkeWj0JhsLo9TBagiCma6NALUzmKy2fWOOmEXz7Z0KgR25WXG529WauZPXVpQsfL4huj-Q7m0Fy602mFyR3O13AIA)